# Kак уменьшить число итераций во внутреннем цикле?

Tags: java

Вопрос: как уменьшит число итераций внутреннего цикла?
Изначальное количество тактов: 4851, в моем же решении только 3528.
Подскажите правильно ли мое решение и можно ли внести какие-то улучшения(?):

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int takt=0;

        for(int i=2;i<=100;i++)
        tochka:{
            System.out.print("\nDeliteli chisla " +i+": " );

            for(int j=2; j<i; j++){
                if((i%j)==0)System.out.print(j + ", ");
                if(i==(j+1) | j==50)break tochka;
                takt++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("TAKT: "+takt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я бы вот это `j<i;` заменил на `j*j<=i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поиска всех делителей числа существует много приёмов. Первый из них - сначала отыскать все простые делители `p1**a1`, `p2**a2`, ..., `pn**an` (где `**` обозначает возведение в степень). Далее перебираем все возможные комбинации степеней `0<=b1<=a1` для простого делителя `p1`, `0<=b2<=a2` для простого делителя `p2`, и так далее. Все ваши делители в ходе этого перебора будут вычисляться по формуле `p1**b1 * p2**b2 * ... * pn**bn`. Однако нужно вручную исключить два крайних случая: `1` и само число, с которого начали расчёты. Этот способ быстрый, у него будет не много итераций, а именно, столько, сколько всего делителей + время разложения на множители (есть очень быстрые алгоритмы).

Второй способ правильно указан в комментарии: коль скоро в любом разложении на два множителя `a*b=c`, у вас всегда либо `a`, либо `b` НЕ превосходит квадратного корня из `c`, вам нужно проверять делители только ДО корня из `i` (включительно). Таким образом, если у вас получилось `(i%j)==0`, то значит имеете сразу два делителя числа `i`: само число `j` и число, равное `i/j`, если, конечно, оба эти числа различны.

Comment: Нк очень понятен первый способ. Но вы можете примерно оценить количество итераций в первом способе? Например, во втором итераций будет меньше 1000, где то в районе 600-700.

Comment: @tym32167 а что считать итерацией? Я ответ выложу с кодом, но что именно итерация то?)

Comment: Я могу точно сказать число итераций в первом способе. Оно в точности равно количеству делителей и меньше быть не может в принципе, потому что я так понял задачу, нужно *вывести* все делители. Плюс число итераций в разложении числа на множители (это зависит от алгоритма).

Итерацией в первом способе следует считать прибавление единицы к вектору состояний `(b0, b1, .., bn)`. Считайте, что когда `b0` станет равным `a0`, мы обнуляем `b0` и прибавляем единицу к `b1`... ну и так далее, пока не дойдём до последнего состояния `(a0, a1, ..., an)`.

Comment: @pavel я так понимаю, это про счетчик во внутреннем цикле (в вопросе переменная `takt`)

Comment: @tym32167 у меня порядка 774 получилось) Но опять же цикла вложенного то нет)

Comment: @Zealint сорри, вы уже дважды пояснили ваш алгоритм, но я так и не понял его суть. Видимо, у меня сегодня лыжи не едут :)

Comment: @tym32167 да ничего страшного, поедут когда-нибудь :)

Comment: @tym32167 Вот здесь с подробностями: https://zaochnik.com/spravochnik/matematika/delimost/nahozhdenie-vseh-delitelej-chisla/

Comment: Вообще, если уж на то пошло, я выскажу своё авторитетное мнение :) Число итераций как сделано у автора - это бесполезная оценка эффективности решения. Эффективность складывается не только из числа, но из качества (характера) самих вычислений. Первый способ, который я описал, может дать очень быстрое решение, даже если в нём будет в сто раз больше каких-нибудь итераций. Это зависит множества факторов, в том числе от квалификации оптимизатора кода.

Comment: Я просто вот что думаю: вот у нас есть числа от 1 до 100, максимальный делитель может быть 10, верно? Тогда если просто посчитать от 2 до 10, и на итерации для 2 отметить все числа, что делятся на 2 (2, 4, 6, 8, 10..), потом все числа. что делятся на 3 (3,6,9,12) и так далее до 10, то будет всего примерно 200 итераций, за который мы полностью решим задачу

Comment: Что то типа [такого](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDqpj.png) - тольео я там массив использовал, чисто для наглядности, можно также и HashSet использовать для этого.

Comment: @tym32167 У числа 100 собственные делители такие: 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50. Не вижу у вас вывода этой последовательности.

Comment: У числа 100 в моей таблице будут отмечены 2, 4, 5 и 10. То есть делители будут 2 и 100/2=50, 4 и 100/4=25, 5 и 100/5=20, 10 и 100/10 - тот же 10.

Comment: @tym32167, да, но ровно то же самое я и описал в качестве второго варианта, только вы оптимизировали ситуацию таким образом, что проверяете не все делители, а только нужные. Однако у вас используется целая матрица, что крайне плохо для больших чисел. Можно ли обойтись обычным битовым массивом? Мне кажется, что можно и очень легко.

Comment: Не совсем, второй вариант - это вы его взяли из моего комментария, там будет примерно 600-700 интераций, этот вариант - только 200 итераций. Про память и большие числа пока речи не идет, но конечно, тут есть где сэкономить.

Comment: Привет ребята, сбасибо что подкинули пищи для мозга. Вариант j*j<=i оказался хорош при дополнении:   
if((i%j)==0){System.out.print(j + ", ");
int k=i/j;
if(k!=j)System.out.print(k + ", ");}    
Тогда выводятся все делители числа, ну а число итераций 525.

Answer (score 0):

Например можно использовать решето Эрастосфена для эффективной факторизации.

```
int N = 100;
int er[] = new int[N+1];
for (int i=2; i <= N; i++)
    if (er[i] == 0){
        for (int j=i; j<=N; j+=i)
            er[j] = i;
        System.out.println("1 " + i);
    } else {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
        for (int j=i; j>1; j/=er[j])
            m.compute(er[j], (a,b) -> b==null?1:b+1);
        int z = 1;
        Object to[] = m.entrySet().toArray();
        int[] get = new int[to.length];
        System.out.print("1");
        while (true){
            int j = 0;
            for (; j < to.length; j++){
                Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> s = (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>) to[j];
                if (get[j] < s.getValue()){
                    get[j]++;
                    z*=s.getKey();
                    break;
                } else {
                    for (; z%s.getKey() == 0; z/= s.getKey());
                    get[j] = 0;
                }
            }
            if (j == to.length)
                break;
            System.out.print(" " + z);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Что считать итерацией - вопрос интересный, но у меня получилось порядка 780.

P.S. код можно ещё оптимизировать.